# Convertir string a Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy recibiendo como respuesta de una api un string de esta forma:

```
"[{name: Jonh, last_name: Doe}, {name: Michael, last_name: Jackson}]"
```

Como podría convertirlo a una Map<String, dynamic>

Intente crear un modelo con quicktype.io de esta forma:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Companies {
  Companies({
    required this.idReg,
    required this.nombreEmpresa,
  });

  String idReg;
  String nombreEmpresa;

  factory Companies.fromJson(String str) => Companies.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Companies.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Companies(
        idReg: json["id_reg"],
        nombreEmpresa: json["nombre_empresa"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id_reg": idReg,
        "nombre_empresa": nombreEmpresa,
      };
}
```

Para implementarlo asi:

```
String jsonCompanies = json.encode(Preferences.companies);

  final companies = Companies.fromJson(jsonCompanies);

  print(companies);
```

y me da este error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Comment: Me surgen dudas sobre lo que necesitas... ¿Porqué a un List<Map<String key, String value>>?, quiero decir, ¿cual sería la clave de ese Json?, por otro lado, ¿consigues leer el json, hasta donde has coseguido hacer algo? ¿consigues que java recoja los datos?

Comment: @chikebox lo necesito asi para poder mapear los valores de cada usuario. No uso java, estoy programando en dart.

Answer (score 0):

En la parte donde le asignas a la variable `jsonCompanies` estás convirtiendo un dato de tipo `String` nuevamente a `String` y por esa razón te salta ese error, porque el `json.encode` transforma una lista o un mapa en una cadena `String`, entonces, lo que tienes que hacer en primera instancia, como no sabemos que tipo de datos nos va a retornar tu json a la variable `jsonCompanies` cambiale el tipo de `String` a `final` y en vez de usar `json.encode`, usa `json.decode` para transformar un `String` en el formato que te regresa el json:

```
final jsonCompanies = json.decode(Preferences.companies);
```

Con eso ya solucionarias ese error

Comment: Gracias por responder. Cuando lo pongo asi me salta este error. FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)
[{id_reg: 7WC8JU9DQH, nombre_empresa: Test1}]

Comment: En la primera línea de código, mira a ver si te deja poner en la parte de Preferences.companies el .body => Preferences.companies.body